# MySQL statement with wildcards using PHP is not working

Tags: php, mysql

Solved: Not sure why, but after I reloaded LAMP stack everything started to work just fine. Thank all of you for help!

I have following MySQL statement prepared in PHP:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE (country LIKE 'Latvia' AND phone NOT LIKE '371%')
```

which selects records with incorrect country phone codes.
In php it looks like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM {$table_name} WHERE (
    country LIKE '$country' AND phone NOT LIKE '$phone_code%')";
```

While it perfectly filters records in phpMyAdmin, it doesn't works in my application - I get all of the records in including correct ones. Your help is really appreciated!

EDIT:
Here's how more code looks like:

```
    while ($row = $this->fetch_array($result_set)) {
        $countries_to_check[$row['short_name']] = $row['calling_code'];
    }
    $i = 1;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM {$this->table_name} WHERE ";
    foreach ($countries_to_check as $country => $phone_code) {
        if ($i > 1) {
            $sql .= " OR ";
        }
        $sql .= "(country LIKE '".$country."' AND phone NOT LIKE '".$phone_code."%')";
        $i++;
    }
    $result_set = $this->query($sql);
```

As I wrote in comments, all the variables are not empty, I have echoed $sql and even ran this query in phpMyAdmin, with success.

Result looks like this:

```
country     phone   
Lithuania           37028694529 * Correct
Latvia      37122171755 * Correct
Latvia      37522433153     * Incorrect
Latvia      +37126378238    * Incorrect
```

Comment: what do you get when you echo your query in php?  Are all the variables there?

Comment: if you're using prepared statements you should probably show some more code describing how you use them..

Comment: 371% means start with 371

Comment: It seems `$country` is empty in your query, as @SureshKamrushi said, try to echo your query

Comment: I have actually copy-pasted echo from $sql at the beginning.

Comment: Could you show an example result set that this gives you?

Comment: Does this work for you ? `$sql = "SELECT * FROM {$table_name} WHERE (
    country LIKE '%'.'$country' AND phone NOT LIKE '$phone_code'.'%')";`

Comment: please paste more code. check your $country, $phone_code variable. it might be empty so that you get all the records

Comment: @JuliusTilvikas if it's solved, please, answer your own question and validate it. This way, it won't come up in `unanswered questions`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Or with  [curly syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex)

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM {$table_name} WHERE (
    country LIKE '{$country}' AND phone NOT LIKE '{$phone_code}%')";
```

Answer (score -4):

It must be this way:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM {$table_name} WHERE (
country LIKE '".$country."' AND phone NOT LIKE '".$phone_code."%')";
```

Comment: Not necessarily. PHP lets you embed variables in a string as shown in the original question.